# Colliding picture boxes, random location not working

Tags: c#, arrays, picturebox, overlap, overlapping

I've been trying to make a array of images that are created randomly in a space, the thing is when they overlap, they are not changing they're location.

```
    int number;

    PictureBox[] X = new PictureBox[100]; 

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void addX(int number)
    {
        Random randomNumber = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
        int x = randomNumber.Next(0, reprezentare.Height - 40);
        int y = randomNumber.Next(0, reprezentare.Width - 40);
        X[number] = new PictureBox();
        X[number].Height = 41;
        X[number].Width = 41;
        X[number].SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
        X[number].Image = Properties.Resources.X;

        if(number >= 1)
        {
            while (pictureBox1.Bounds.IntersectsWith(X[number - 1].Bounds)) x = randomNumber.Next(0, reprezentare.Height - 40);
            while (pictureBox1.Bounds.IntersectsWith(X[number - 1].Bounds)) y = randomNumber.Next(0, reprezentare.Width - 40);
        }

        X[number].Location = new Point(x, y);
        reprezentare.Controls.Add(X[number]);
        number++;

        richTextBox1.Text += x + " : " + y;
        richTextBox1.Text += Environment.NewLine;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        addX(number);
    }
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: what happens out of curiosity what happens when you use the debugger and step through the code? do you notice anything that jumps out in regards to what's not expected..? or unexpected behavior ..?

Comment: You seem to test only if a new image overlaps with the previous one. Not with all others.

Comment: Don't do `new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);` - it just the same as doing `new Random()` in terms of getting a seed. Better yet you should really push this declaration out as a private field and only ever declare it once.

Comment: What are the values of `reprezentare.Height` & `reprezentare.Width`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of issues.  First, you have a variable `number` and a parameter `number`.  Not good:

```
int number;
private void addX(int number)
```

Just change it to:

```
private void addX()
```

Secondly, you are only comparing against PictureBox1, so all of the PictureBoxes you are adding aren't checking the other PictureBoxes, so you can try something like this:

```
bool ok = false;
while (!ok) {
  ok = true;
  int x = randomNumber.Next(0, reprezentare.Width - 40);
  int y = randomNumber.Next(0, reprezentare.Height - 40);
  for (int i = 0; i < number; ++i) {
    if (X[i].Bounds.IntersectsWith(new Rectangle(x, y, 41, 41))) {
      ok = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (ok) {
    X[number].Location = new Point(x, y);
  }
}
reprezentare.Controls.Add(X[number]);
number++;
```

You would have to add a check to see if any space is still available or not to avoid the loop going to infinity.